# How to 'tag' a location in a C source file for a later breakpoint definition?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, gdb, breakpoints

**Problem:**
I want to be able to put different potentially unique or repeated "tags" across my C code, such that I can use them in gdb to create breakpoints.

**Similar Work:**

- **Breakpoints to line-numbers:** The main difference with breakpoints on source lines, is that if the code previous to the tag is modified in such a way that it results in more or less lines, a reference to the tag would still be semantically correct, a reference to the source line would not.
- **Labels:** I am coming from my previous question, [How to tell gcc to keep my unused labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086938/how-to-tell-gcc-to-keep-my-unused-labels), in which I preconceived the idea that the answer was to insert labels. Upon discussion with knowledgeable members of the platform, I was taught that label's names are not preserved after compilation. Labels not used within C are removed by the compiler.
- **Injecting asm labels:** Related to the previous approach, if I inject asm code in the C source, certain problems arise, due to inline functions, compiler optimizations, and lack of scoping. This makes this approach not robust.
- **Define a dummy function:** On this other question, [Set GDB breakpoint in C file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671560/set-gdb-breakpoint-in-c-file), there is an interesting approach, in which a "dummy" function can be placed in the code, and then add a breakpoint to the function call. The problem with this approach is that the definition of such function must be replicated for each different tag.

Is there a better solution to accomplish this? Or a different angle to attack the presented problem?

Comment: Do you care about debugging optimized builds, i.e. still having somewhere meaningful for the breakpoint to be?  Either way you'd want a way to `#define` it away to be able to make a fully optimized build without anything slowing it down, but you might also want a build that's optimized but still has findable breakpoints.

Comment: I would use python to search the source file for your **tags**, and automatically [set the breakpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints-In-Python.html).

Comment: @PeterCordes Not caring too much about optimized builds.

Comment: @ssbssa, this sounds interesting, could you please post a minimal toy example?

Answer (score 3):

Using SDT (Statically Defined Tracing) probe points appears to satisfy all the requirements.

GDB [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Static-Probe-Points.html) links to examples of how to define the probes.

[Example use](https://blog.sergiodj.net/2012/10/27/gdb-and-systemtap-probes-part-2.html): `(gdb) break -probe-stap my_probe` (this should be documented in the [GDB breakpoints section](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks), but currently isn't).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a dummy variable and set it to different values. Then you can use conditional watchpoints. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static volatile int loc;
int main()
{
    loc = 1;
    puts("hello world");
    loc = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
(gdb) watch loc if loc == 2
Hardware watchpoint 1: loc
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
hello world

Hardware watchpoint 1: loc

Old value = 1
New value = 2
main () at test.c:8
8       return 0;
```

You can of course wrap the assignment in a macro so you only get it in debug builds. Usual caveats apply: optimizations and inlining may be affected.

Answer (score 2):

Use python to search a source file for some predefined labels, and [set breakpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints-In-Python.html) there:

```
def break_on_labels(source, label):
    """add breakpoint on each SOURCE line containing LABEL"""
    with open(source) as file:
        l = 0
        for line in file:
            l = l + 1
            if label in line:
                gdb.Breakpoint(source=source, line=l)

main_file = gdb.lookup_global_symbol("main").symtab.fullname()
break_on_labels(main_file, "BREAK-HERE")
```

Example:

```
int main(void)
{
  int a = 15;
  a = a + 23; // BREAK-HERE
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could insert a `#warning` at each line where you want a breakpoint, then have a script to parse the file and line numbers from the compiler messages and write a `.gdbinit` file placing breakpoints at those locations.